# Why is Disk 0 gone everywhere?

Tags: linux, windows, bios

So the other day, I installed Arch Linux with GRUB to dualboot, and when I came back to Windows, Disk Management was blank, and `list disk` didn't have Disk 0 as well. How do I go about fixing this, I've tried resetting Windows, but it fails, I tried a fresh install and it said that there was no driver for storage? I even used the NZXT restore, and that failed too...

Hereby some screenshots:
Disk management:
[image: disk management]
List disk:
[image: list disk]

Comment: Restore Windows from your last disk image.

Comment: I don't have a restore image...

Comment: we don't know. if the physical disk is not discovered, it may be improperly connected or kaput.

Comment: Is the drive recognized by `smartctl` _(for Linux, install `smartmontools`, for Windows,  download directly from [`smartmontools`](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Download#InstalltheWindowspackage) - command is the same for both)_: `smartctl -a /dev/sda; smartctl -t short /dev/sda; sleep 120; smartctl -a /dev/sda` If it's not detected by `smartctl`, shutdown the PC, disconnect power, repeatedly press the power button for 30s to discharge all capacitors, then reseat the drive's power connector and both ends of the SATA cable _Cont'd..._

Comment: _Cont'd..._ Also ensure you're not exceeding the wattage for the 5v & 12v circuit, but if that's verified and connectors have been reseated, test a known good drive on the same power connector and SATA cable - if it's recognized, the other drive has mechanically or electrically failed. If Windows errors with lacking a driver for storage, it's likely a more recent version of Windows needs to be used, since that usually refers to lacking an NTFS driver within the Windows boot files and is more commonly seen on outdated WinPE/WinRE WIMs

Comment: `smartctl` can detect it